# Pandas DataFrame: how to get column mean valuebut taking into account only the rows that have lower index than the one I want to get the mean

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate, mean

The problem I have is I want to predict the victory of a team over another one, to do that I want to have for each match the winrate of each team before the date of the match.

However using a `df.groupBy("teamName").agg({"isVictory":"mean"})` provides me the global wirate of the team that is not usable because you are not supposed to know the winrate of all matches at this instant.

So what I would like, is to get the winrate of the matches before this one, knowing that I have a column `index` in my DataFrame that keep the order of the match (i.e. if the index of a match is lower than the index of the current match it means the match has been made before, thus this match should be considered in the mean)

Note that my columns are :

> indexMatch, nameTeam, isVictoryTeam

(isVictoryTeam= if Team1 won and 0 if the Team lost )

an example of the dataset:

```
   IndexMatch  isVictoryTeam team   winrate
0           1              1    a       NaN
1           2              0    a         1
2           3              1    a       0.5
3           4              1    a    0.6667
```

The winrate is the output expected.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you provide an example of your dataframe as well as desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a better way, but this one works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'team': [' a', ' a', ' a', ' a', 'b', 'b', 'c'],
                   'IndexMatch': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                   'isVictoryTeam': [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]})
df['winrate'] = df.groupby('team')['isVictoryTeam'].expanding().mean().reset_index().groupby('team')['isVictoryTeam'].shift().reset_index(drop=True)
df
#   IndexMatch  isVictoryTeam team   winrate
#0           1              1    a       NaN
#1           2              0    a  1.000000
#2           3              1    a  0.500000
#3           4              1    a  0.666667
#4           5              0    b       NaN
#5           6              1    b  0.000000
#6           7              1    c       NaN
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted !